# why the comparison of int(char) does not work?

Tags: c++

I am trying to check whether an integer is an uppercase or lowercase or a digit in the following way

```
if(int('A')<=int(M[i])<=int('Z')) cout<<"upper"<<endl;
if(int('a')<=int(M[i])<=int('z'))  cout<<lower"<<endl;
if (int('0')<=int(M[i])<=int('9')) cout<<"digit"<<endl;
```

But all if statements return true for any character and thus all 3 strings are printed for any character. Why I cannot compare the converted int from chars for this test ? `

Comment: You can't chain operators in C++ and have it do what you expect; do `if ('A' <= M[i] && M[i] <= 'Z')`. Also you don't need the casts (at least for the char literals).

Comment: Why not just use `std::isupper` etc?

Comment: @chris Because it wouldn't be clever enough. Also, it would be way too portable.

Comment: @user3175411: well, you can, it just doesn't do what you expect. For that use Python.

Comment: @chris:- i could but i was just trying to find the error with this one

Comment: @H2CO3, Well, to be fair, one that actually operates on a UTF-8 character or something would work better.

Comment: why so many negative votes ? do you expect every questioner to know c++ specific details -- some of us are just learning different languages which allow all this

Comment: @cleanplay that's spelled "expect", not "accept". And yes, you are expected to learn the basic syntax (this is very basic syntax) of the language you are working with.

Comment: Probably the lack of program solving effort. If you think there is a problem with `int(char)` comparisons, then try comparing e.g. simple `int` literals and see what happens.

Comment: thanks, i understand your points as well

Comment: @cleanplay I did not downvote you, but one way to think of votes: would the question, as asked, be useful if searched for and found on google using words used in the question?  One good thing to do is to http://sscce.org and simplify your problem down to something essential, with fewer confounding details.

Comment: @chris Making it work for UTF-8 is far from trivial.  But his code, even with the corrections, doesn't work on any of the machines I know: there are capital letters whose encoding isn't between `'A'` and `'Z'` (and there are machines where there are characters which aren't capital letters in the interval between `'A'` and `'Z'`).

Comment: @JamesKanze, Very true.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2011/11/ruby-does-equality-right-and-c-does-not/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain comparison is not supported in C++

```
a <= b <= c
```

is parsed as

```
(a <= b) <= c
```

i.e. you're comparing the result of first comparison with `c` and this is permitted in your case because the result of a comparison can be implicitly converted to an integer (thus hiding the logic error).

The C++ solution for range checking is

```
(a <= b) && (b <= c)
```

but of course you've to pay attention that if `b` is an expression with side effects it can be evaluated twice and so it may be necessary to store its value in a variable to use this form.

Comment: Note that with user-defined types (as opposed to int) it is possible to let <= return an object that is convertible to bool but also keeps a reference to its (extreme) arguments and has overloaded comparison operators. Probably not a good idea, but possible.